# Core-Plot - preferredNumberOfMajorTicks do not limit the number of Ticks

Tags: ios, core-plot

I want to draw only 10 Majors Ticks on my Y axis. For that I'm using the methode `preferredNumberOfMajorTicks = 10`.

but as seen on the screenshot, it doesn't really work ...

[image: bad Y axis ticks]

Here is my configuration for the y axis :

```
    CPTXYAxis *y = axisSet.yAxis;
y.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyFixedInterval;
//y.majorIntervalLength = CPTDecimalFromDouble(2);
y.preferredNumberOfMajorTicks = 10;
y.minorTicksPerInterval = 5;
y.tickDirection = CPTSignNone;
y.majorTickLineStyle = majorLineStyle;
y.minorTickLineStyle = minorLineStyle;
y.axisLineStyle = majorLineStyle;
y.majorTickLength = 7.0;
y.minorTickLength = 5.0;
y.labelTextStyle = whiteTextStyle;
y.minorTickLabelTextStyle = minorTickBlackTextStyle;
y.titleTextStyle = whiteTextStyle;

y.axisConstraints = [CPTConstraints constraintWithLowerOffset:40.0];
```

Something should over right the methode `preferredNumberOfMajorTicks = 10` but I cannot see what ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `preferredNumberOfMajorTicks` property does not apply to the fixed interval labeling policy. See the [Core Plot docs](http://core-plot.googlecode.com/hg/documentation/html/iOS/interface_c_p_t_axis.html#afa9a0f51aa4558e19948797f01ffc32b) for details. You have two options here:

1. Keep the fixed interval labeling policy and change the `majorIntervalLength` to a value that will give the desired number of ticks.
2. Change the labeling policy to `CPTAxisLabelingPolicyAutomatic` or `CPTAxisLabelingPolicyEqualDivisions`.

Comment: That was the solution, it sound evident now. Thank you for your quick answer Eric